# Typescript does not recognize static methods of class

Tags: typescript, class, constructor, sequelize.js

I have a typescript function with a generic class named "Model". This class has a static method "build". Typescript does not recognize the static methods of the class and shows me this error. The compiled javasript does work without errors:

```ts
export function dataToInstance(model: Model, data: any) {
    if (!data) {
        return data;
    }

    const include = generateIncludeRecurse(model);
    const instance = model.build(data, { isNewRecord: false, raw: false, include });
    restoreTimestamps(data, instance);
    return instance;
}
```

Error: [image]

How can i get typescript to accept the static methods. I already tried "typeof" but then typescript throws errors because model is an abstract class.

Comment: Can you post a complete, working, reproducible example on the TypeScript playground? It's hard to offer suggestions without more info about the types and logic involved.

Comment: For your info the error given in german means: "Property 'build' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any>'. Did you mean to access the static member 'Model<any, any>.build' instead?ts(2576)"

Answer (score 0):

Your function says it would like to receive a model, and you would like to do XYZ with that model in the body of the function. By saying model is of type `Model`, we are PRECISELY telling typescript that every time this function is called, it can expect the `model` argument to have all properties and methods specified in the type `Model`.

Investigate the `Model` type. It looks like a generic that takes two parameters. Without seeing `Model`, its impossible to say for sure. The type parameters are probably responsible for intersecting the base of a `Model` with additional properties/methods.

This might not be your code, but Something like `Model<{ build: BuildFn }>` that lets typescript know the model you are working with has a build property on it.

Hopefully this helps you in one way or another.